# Android scrolling in card view

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

I have this XML layout in my app which contains a `ListView` and `CardView` but the `CardView` content is hiding below the screen sometimes, I want to apply scrolling to the whole layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <include
                android:id="@id/tool"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lvcontent"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                card_view:contentPadding="8dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvcusttest"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:text="What Customers are Saying"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tvcusttest"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                        android:paddingRight="3dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/cpiBanner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    app:fillColor="#ffffff"
                    app:pageColor="#80cccccc" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/vpCustomerTestimonials"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"></View>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cardView3"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnviewcart"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="@color/selecteditem"
                    android:text="View Cart"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="23sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What is going wrong? When the screen size is small, the half layout hides below the screen. I just want is to apply a scroll behavior to this. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Put layout inside a scroll view and the use of recyclerview instead of list view may solve your issue. If you are using listview itself you have to then you have to handle the scroll and swipe of scroll view seperately

Comment: i have to use listview itself,,so suggest accordingly

Comment: when i put scrollview above that linear layout then it only scrolls the list view and the card view contetn still hides below the screen

Comment: You have to use footer view for it, put cardview xml content in footer view and then add it to listview. @neha

Comment: but when i am using footer view the cardview's content get a black background

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a listview, you can add a footer. Like this

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

And then the footer layout

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lvcontent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="8dp">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvcusttest"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="What Customers are Saying"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvcusttest"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                    android:paddingRight="3dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/cpiBanner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:padding="1dp"
                app:fillColor="#ffffff"
                app:pageColor="#80cccccc" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/vpCustomerTestimonials"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the Activity class will be

```
public class MyListActivty extends ListActivity {
    private Context context = null;
    private ListView list = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //code to set adapter to populate list
        View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);
    }
}
```

Even so, still consider using a recyclerview.

Comment: u mean i have to make two different xmls one for listview and another is footer layout which contains cardview,,???/and then set this in main activity file

Comment: that is true. You will have a separate xml file for the footer design.